# Drawing line graphics leads Flash to spiral out of control!

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, graphics

I'm having problems with some AS3 code that simply draws on a `Sprite`'s `Graphics` object. The drawing happens as part of a larger procedure called on every `ENTER_FRAME` event of the `stage`.

Flash neither crashes nor returns an error. Instead, it starts running at 100% CPU and grabs all the memory that it can, until I kill the process manually or my computer buckles under the pressure when it gets up to around 2-3 GB. This will happen at a random time, and without any noticiple slowdown beforehand.

WTF? Has anyone seen anything like this?

PS: I used to do the drawing within a `MOUSE_MOVE` event handler, which brought this problem on even faster.

PPS: I'm developing on Linux, but reproduced the same problem on Windows.

**UPDATE**: You asked for some code, so here we are. The drawing function looks like this:

```
public static function drawDashedLine(i_graphics : Graphics, i_from : Point, i_to : Point, i_on : Number, i_off : Number) : void
{
    const vecLength : Number = Point.distance(i_from, i_to);

    i_graphics.moveTo(i_from.x, i_from.y);

    var dist : Number = 0;
    var lineIsOn : Boolean = true;
    while(dist < vecLength)
    {
        dist = Math.min(vecLength, dist + (lineIsOn ? i_on : i_off));
        const p : Point = Point.interpolate(i_from, i_to, 1 - dist / vecLength);
        if(lineIsOn) i_graphics.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
        else i_graphics.moveTo(p.x, p.y);

        lineIsOn = !lineIsOn;
    }
}
```

and is called like this (`m_graphicsLayer` is a `Sprite`):

```
m_graphicsLayer.graphics.clear();
if (m_destinationPoint)
{
    m_graphicsLayer.graphics.lineStyle(2, m_fixedAim ? 0xff0000 : 0x333333, 1);
    drawDashedLine(m_graphicsLayer.graphics, m_initialPos, m_destinationPoint, 10, 10);
}
```

Comment: you could start by showing us some code :)

Comment: yeah, show us your code,sounds like you have an infinite loop in there somewhere.

Comment: Yep, if you start firing off drawing commands on enterframe or on a mouse event, each iteration can start colliding with the next firing if you don't handle things efficiently.

Comment: @liquidleaf- what do you mean by "colliding with the next firing"? is it possible for an event handler to be called again before it has finished? or do you just mean that it takes so much time that the next frame will be skipped?

Comment: Yes, I do.  There can be multiple events active at one time.  Say you set an EnterFrame event.  Then, you set your framerate to be 30fps.  If your application doesn't have time to finish one EnterFrame call, it will still go on to the next call and this will fire another separate event.  It is not linear... one event will not wait for another to finish, and they can and will overlap and compound.  A very heavy function executed on an event basis can easily crash a machine without causing a compilation error.

Comment: The timeline simply fires off it's event... more or less broadcast "I hit a frame, do something", "I hit a frame again, do something again"... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> while(dist < vecLength)

This should always jump out as a red flag during debugging and code review, especially if the arguments come from a calculation which you can't reliably predict when writing code, or the values don't have a strict upper limit (like Point.distance() or Math.min()).

Been bitten by those a number of times. :-)

Comment: You're right. Still though, why would Flash the way it does, grabbing all this memory and never releasing it?

Comment: Probably because the method is stuck in a infinite loop which allocates more resources with each iteration, and never releases them back. It just keeps going until the process breaks down.

Answer (score 0):

Well, CookieOfFortune was right- there was an infinite loop in the case that one of the end points was at infinity (which wasn't supposed to happen ;)

Thanks for your help.